# Jelastic, deploy DropWizard application

Tags: dropwizard, jelastic

I have a Dropwizard application that works fine locally, but I can not figure out how to deploy it into my Jelastic environment.
I read "Hosting Spring Boot Standalone and Clustered Java Applications with Jelastic Cloud" [tutorial](https://blog.jelastic.com/2017/04/27/hosting-spring-boot-java-applications) but seems like it is more focused on Spring Boot applications. To run my DropWizard app I need to execute

```
java -jar myJar.jar server config.yml
```

but from the tutorial it seems that Elastic just executes the jar without providing "server" and "config.yml" parameters.
So when I upload and deploy my jar file (I tried both, jar and zip approaches) all I can see in the output is

```
    Node ID : XXXXX
-----------------------
Deploy failed
/opt/repo/jelastic/scripts/deploy.sh line 66 clearCache command not found
zipinfo  cannot find or open /, /.zip or /.ZIP.
zipinfo  cannot find or open /, /.zip or /.ZIP.

Error Nothing to run
```

and SpringBoot log is empty.
Can you please tell me is there a way to deploy a DropWizard application, or the only way to deploy it is using docker registry?

Comment: The issue you are reffering to is supposed to be a deffect in deploy script that is already fixed. Could you, please check one more time?

Comment: I see the same error log, the only difference is that it no longer contains a reference to 'deploy.sh' script. My jar file contains application.yml file in the root and manifest file in META-INF. I tried creating a zip archive with config/application.yml and lib/fileName.jar files.

Answer (score 0):

To provide parameters to your application you need to edit file variables.conf from your dashboard, then just restart the application